# C++ Overloading input with abstract class

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual, virtual-inheritance

I am trying to build a "candy shop user interface" and I have 4 classes:

1. SweetItem class - abstract base class
2. Candy, Cookie, IceCream classes - derived from the base class virtually
3. Cookielida - derived from both cookie and ice cream classes

Now I have in the base class:

```
class SweetItem
{
public:
    /*=====Builders & Destructor & = Operator=====*/
    SweetItem();
    SweetItem(const SweetItem&);
    ~SweetItem();
    const SweetItem& operator=(const SweetItem&);

    /*=====Input\Output operators=====*/
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const SweetItem&);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream&, SweetItem&);

    /*=====Static members=====*/
    static void NoSweets() { cout << num_sweets; }
    static int get_num() { return num_sweets; }

    /*=====Virtual Interface=====*/
    virtual SweetItem* clone() const = 0;
    virtual SweetItem* enter() = 0;
    virtual void print() const = 0;
    virtual int get_amount() const =0;
    virtual float get_price() const = 0;
    virtual String get_type() const = 0;
    virtual float get_total() const = 0;

    /*=====Cyber Function=====*/
    void color(const int) const;
protected:
private:
    static int num_sweets;
};
```

The input/output are calling virtual functions "enter()" and "print()":

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& op, const SweetItem& input) {
    if(&input)
        input.print();
    return op;
}
istream& operator>>(istream& ip, SweetItem& input) {
    input.enter();
    return ip;
}
```

When I try to use the "enter()" of the cookielida like this:

```
int main() {
    SweetItem* temp = new Cookielida;
    cin >> *temp;
    cout << *temp << endl;
}
```

It prints a default object that i set up instead  of the entered selection by user. This is the virtual implementation:

```
SweetItem* Cookielida::enter() {
    String ct, it;
    float cp, ip;
    cout << "Please select from the available options: " << endl;
    cout << "1) Butter cookies " << BUTTERP << "$ per unit" << endl;
    cout << "2) Chocolate chip cookies " << CHIPP << "$ per unit" << endl;
    cout << "3) Oreo cookies " << OREOP << "$ per unit" << endl;
    int opt1;
    opt1 = error(1, 3);
    switch (opt1)
    {
    case BUTTER: ct = "Butter cookies";
        cp = BUTTERP;
        break;
    case CHIP: ct = "Chocolate chip cookies";
        cp = CHIPP;
        break;
    case OREO: ct = "Oreo cookies";
        cp = OREOP;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    cout << "Please select from the available options: " << endl;
    cout << "1) Vanilla icecream " << VANIP << "$ per unit" << endl;
    cout << "2) Chocolate icecream " << CHOCP << "$ per unit" << endl;
    cout << "3) Yogurt icecream " << YOGUP << "$ per unit" << endl;
    int opt2;
    opt2 = error(1, 3);
    switch (opt2)
    {
    case VANI: it = "Vanilla icecream";
        ip = VANIP;
        break;
    case CHOC: it = "Chocolate icecream";
        ip = CHOCP;
        break;
    case YOGU: it = "Yogurt icecream";
        ip = YOGUP;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    cout << "How many cookielidas do you want? " << endl;
    int a;
    a = error(0, MAXAMOUNT);
    SweetItem* temp = new Cookielida(a, ip, cp, it, ct);
    return temp;
}
```

I believe that the problem is that the temp cookielida created in the "enter()" function is destroyed instead of copied to the temp in the "main()".
Also these are the constructors:

```
Cookielida::Cookielida(int a=0, float ip=0, float cp=0, const String& it="", const String& ct="") :
IceCream(ICEA, ip, it), Cookie(COKA, cp, ct), amount(a), price((ip + cp * 2)*1.5), type(ct + " " + it)
{

}
Cookielida::Cookielida(const Cookielida& input) :
IceCream(ICEA, input.get_ip(), input.get_it()), 
Cookie(COKA, input.get_cp(), input.get_ct()), 
amount(input.amount), price(input.price), type(input.type)
{

}
```

This is the output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `enter()` function. It doesn't change the object itself, but rather creates a new one which is returned via pointer. So when you call `input.enter();` in your `operator>>` overload, the class `input` refers to is not varied -- and in fact, nothing happens as the pointer you return is not used at all.

As a workaround, you can do the following

```
Cookielida& Cookielida::enter()  //better return the derived object in a covariant way,
                                 //not the base class pointer
                                 //you can still downcast it if required
{
    //read in those many parameters

    //then either set the class member variables "a, ip, cp, it, ct" 
    //directly (--the preferred way)

    //or use this cheap alternative
    operator=(Cookielida(a, ip, cp, it, ct));
    return *this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just totaly missed the point in design of your `Cookielida::enter` function. It returns totaly new object and does not change the old one.
Putting it is inside `operator>>` is just a nonsense, you may actualy want to put it other way arround.

```
int main() {
    SweetItem* temp = new Cookielida;
    SweetItem* temp2 = temp->enter();
    temp2->print();
    delete temp;
    delete temp2;
}
```